# How to use SqlException in .NET CORE?

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

In my old project with .Net Framework use from

```
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

and

```
if (ex.GetType() == typeof(SqlException))
{
    return ErrorMessage((SqlException)ex);
}
```

and now in .NET CORE Does not know Code above

How to use `typeof(SqlException)` in .NET CORE?

Comment: This will compile just fine in .NET Core. You've likely not added the [`System.Data.SqlClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient) package to your project. Otherwise, provide the exact error message you get, and possibly also the rest of the code to actually compile this, rather than a snippet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In .Net Core version, you need to install this package before using it: [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/)

> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 2.1.4

```c#
try
{
    // code goes here...    
}
catch (SqlException sqlEx)
{
    // code goes here...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // other exception...
}
```

Comment: And to catch either `SqlException` or `SqliteException` within the same block, `DbException` can be used since it's the base for both the _Sql_ and _Sqlite_ providers and no doubt future providers.